# Use of 'If only...'

Tags: conditionals, only

I've looked through conditional clauses and I'm wondering if 'If only he/she'd ......' one of the forms of conditional sentences? Seemed like it didn't match any criteria.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a quote of what you saw?  Confitional  is not a word

Comment: Neither is "sentenses", just to be pedantic.

Comment: If only you could tell us what research you've done, this question might be better.

Comment: Anything with an *if* that can't be dropped is conditional, but what did you mean, please?